# How to include a class from another project under the same Visual Studio Solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

I have two separate projects living in the same VS solution - "PhysicsWrapper" and "Test".
The PhysicsWrapper project has a "Physics" class with its header and cpp file which I want to use in 'test'.
The layout of the solution file system is like so:

```
$(SolutionDir)/
               solution.sln
               PhysicsWrapper/Physics.h & Physics.cpp
               Test/test.cpp
```

In test.cpp I have

```
#include "../PhysicsWrapper/Physics.h"
int main(){
   Physics* p = new Physics();
}
```

and I get the following error:
`LNK2019  unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Physics::Physics(void)" (??0Physics@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main test C:\SolutionDir\test\source.obj`

The things I've tried doing so far that were suggested in similar posts:

1. Include the path to the other project in **C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories** as *$(SolutionDir)\PhysXEngineWrapper* as well as the full path without the macro and changing the include line to simply  `#include "Physics.h"`
2. Including the paths to the libraries (PhysX) used in the "PhysicsWrapper" project in the "Test" project settings.
3. Include the path to the other project in **VC++ Directories -> Include Directories** and **VC++ Directories -> Library Directories** as *$(SolutionDir)\PhysicsWrapper** as well as the full path without the macro.
4. Adding the "PhysicsWrapper" to "Test" 's project build dependencies.

Neither of the solutions helped. Both projects are also built in Debug x64.

EDIT: Also, when using `p->` after the instantiation line I can see all of the methods in the Physics class you'd expect to.

Comment: You need to link the library in the test executable. If they are in the same project you can make it dependent or set the `Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`.

Comment: @drescherjm do you mean that I need to add something like "PhysicsWrapper.lib" in ```Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies``` ? How do I get my PhysicsWrapper project to spit out a lib file when built?

Comment: If PhysicsWrapper is not a library I believe you need to split your project and make it a static library.

Comment: This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=msvc-170) will help you if you need to create or use static library.